# Modify Div Element with javascript

Tags: javascript

My script wont run or the document.getElementById("toMove"); doesn't seem to catch the element. 
Its very basic javascript but I cant understand why its not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
    #toMove
    {
        background-color:lightblue;
        position:absolute;
    }
    </style>
        <script>
        var elem = document.getElementById("toMove");
        elem.style.margin = "600px";
    </script>   
</head>
    <body>  
<div id="toMove" style="margin:200px; font-size:26px;"> Hello World</div> 
    </body>
```

Thanks

Comment: Noticed the `</head` ?

Comment: Yes, thanks. That was just a copy paste error. The main problem was that the element was not in the DOM yet as pointed out bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of reasons why it's not working

1. You need to close the `<head>` tag properly
2. The point at which your script runs, the element with the id `toMove` does not yet exist in the DOM (Document Object Model)

Solving number 1 should be easy enough, just change `</head` to `</head>`. To solve number 2, you need to ensure that the script fires after the element with id `toMove` exists in the DOM. You can do this by hooking up your script to fire when the window has finished loading. The code below sets up a function to fire when the window has finished loading

```
window.onload = function(){
   var elem = document.getElementById("toMove");
   elem.style.margin = "600px";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Close your the  tag properly. Problem is that when your scripts executes your element `toMove` does not exists in DOM

Wrap your code in `window.onload`. The function execute a JavaScript when a page is finished loading.

```
 window.onload = function(){
    var elem = document.getElementById("toMove");
    elem.style.margin = "600px";
 }
```

**OR**, Simply write your script at after you HTML declartion

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this script must run once the DOM is ready (all elements rendered in the browser) Wrap the script like described here:

[pure JavaScript equivalent to jQuery's $.ready() how to call a function when the page/dom is ready for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the)

Or if you use jquery with

`$('document').ready(function(){});`

Answer (score 0):

You must close head tag correctly.

```
</head>
```

And also do the code of Satpal.

Comment: This is rather a comment to Satpal's answer

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, He don't have enough reputation now, Hopefully he will get there

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, its 50

Comment: Sorry, I can't make comments of publications of other people since I get 50 of reputation.

Comment: You will eventually get there mate :). I know that

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>test</title>
        <style>
        #toMove
        {
            background-color:lightblue;
            position:absolute;
        }
        </style>

    </head
        <body>  
    <div id="toMove" style="margin:200px; font-size:26px;"> Hello World</div> 
        </body> 
         <script>
             var elem = document.getElementById("toMove");
              elem.style.margin = "500px";
        </script>  
        </html>
```